# How to use babel6 with .babelrc

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm hitting this [example](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server). I had cloned it and run `npm install`.

Then I try to run `babel lib -d dist`, but I get `ReferenceError: [BABEL] lib/index.js: Unknown option: /home/.../example-node-server/.babelrc.presets`.

What's wrong? How can I properly transpile es6 code with babel6 and `.babelrc` using presets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `babel` from the command line (not from your JavaScript code), install `babel-cli` globally:

```
 npm install -g babel-cli
```

or locally:

```
 npm install babel-cli
```

In case of local install you can run it with:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/babel
```

Comment: Thx you. I fixed it so: `./node_modules/.bin/babel lib -d dist`. You can add it into you answer ;)

Comment: @mqklin Sure, but for local development purposes it's usually preferable to have it globally installed for multiple projects, unless you specifically need separate versions (5 and 6).

Comment: I'm a Babel contributor. Installing globally is _definitely_ not recommended. If you have a module that needs transpiling, Babel should be in that module's deps, otherwise anyone else trying to build your project will have no idea what version of Babel is needed. Generally you'd have an npm script to build for you that automatically references `node_modules`.

Comment: @kyrylkov I think there is a typo in the local installation command (the g flag)